# From what type of distribution does observed z score come from, and based on this picture, what is the variance and mean?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, z-score

[image]

I am trying to understand this conceptually and mathematically but somehow these formulas and variable expressions are confusing. If someone can explain it in simpler terms, it would be appreciated. I am not seeking answers but just a better way to see and approach this problem. Also, what is u(subscript 0)?Thank you :)

Comment: For 'self-study' questions, you should show what you have tried and say why you're not sure how to finish. To start, $z$ should be normal.

Comment: I am assuming if z comes from normal distribution, shouldn't the mean = 0 and variance = 1. But somehow, we have to calculate so I am not entirely sure. I was wondering if mean ux and variance sigma^2x was related  to population AND mean 2ux + 3 and 2^2sigma^2x was related to sample. I know for a fact that z score = (sample mean-population mean)/standard deviation.

Comment: Do we need to plug in numbers or use a certain formula that I am missing?

Comment: You seem to be missing--or not recognizing--the formulas for (a) the variance of a sample mean and (b) the mean and variance of a linear transformation of a random variable. One is given, the other accounts for the $\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: So I have a population mean of 64.6 and a sample mean of 60 (height in inches for females in the nation versus at OSU). So I do 2(60)+3 = 123 for the mean? And I have standard deviation (sigma) of 3 inches and sample of 100 females. So would use 3 or (3/sqrt(100)) for standard deviation? I know I have to square my standard deviation and multiply that by 2^2 (4) to get variance. I am unsure which SD I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints to help you through this: First, let's simplify the notation, letting
$A$ stand for the 'sample mean' and abbreviating $Z_{obs}$ as just $Z.$

Then the main equation can be written as:
$$Z = \frac{A -\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}(A - \mu_0)
= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}A - \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\mu_0.$$

Now, for the next step, you should know that $\mu_A = \mu_0$ and $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma^2/n.$ (A sample mean has the same mean as the population and the variance of the population divided by the sample size. You must have seen
something like that recently.)

Next, we're ready to find the mean and variance of $Z;:$

The mean of $Z$ is $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\mu_A - \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\mu_0.$ (In your first paragraph, let $a = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$ and 
$b = -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}.)$ So the mean of $Z$ simplifies to $0$ because 
$\mu_A = \mu_0.$

The variance of $Z$ is $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}\sigma_A^2.$ (From your first paragraph, the variance has only one term and $a$ gets squared.) So the variance of $Z$ simplifies
t0 $1$ because $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma^2/n.$

Finally, we've shown that the mean of $Z$ is $0$ and the variance of $Z$ is 1.
Also, because $A$ has a normal distribution and we have made a linear 
transformation of $A$ to get $Z,$ we know that $Z$ also has a normal distribution.

So your final answer is that $Z$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1.$

That may seem like a long explanation to get the the end. Just take one
step at a time, looking back in your text or class notes to help with each
piece. I think there are two reasons for giving you this problem. One is to
put these pieces together. The other is that it turns out to be very important
to know that $Z$ has a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: I had one last question. So is the sample mean and population mean the same (equivalent) because the sampling distribution of the sample mean is normal? Just wanted to clarify that. Finally, this made more sense to me. Thank you for your guidance and patience with me. I really appreciate your time and help! We did learn that z scores comes from a standard normal distribution with mean of 0 and variance of 1. I just I could not make the connection somehow.

Comment: Population mean $\mu$ is usually an unknown constant to be estimated. Sample mean (or average) $A= \bar X=\frac 1n \sum_i X_i$ is computed from known data. If the sample is carefully taken then the sample mean accurately estimates $\mu.$ Sample mean $A$ is a random variable with mean $\mu_A = \mu$ and variance $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma^2/n,$ where $\sigma^2$ is population variance (also usually unknown). // Hope you enjoy your statistics class. Things will go best if you read text and class notes before trying problems, then you'll know what to study more deeply in order to work problems.

Comment: Distribution of sample mean is exactly normal if population is normal. If population not normal, then Central Limit Theorem says that sample mean is approx. normal and becomes more nearly normal as $n$ increases. Technical requirement for CLT to work is that population must have a finite variance (in real applications usually the case).